# How to count and store an unknown number of inputs Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to take in an unknown number of strings, each on a new line, count them and determine if they were entered in alphabetical order.

I have to do this without using lists or dictionaries.

I’m lost. I tried assigning each to a variable but realized that without knowing the number of inputs that was not going to work without a loop of some kind that ends when there is no additional input. I have tried that but can’t figure out how to assign a new variable in the loop

Comment: How do you decide when the input ends?

Comment: You can append to the string with a newline. Each line represents a new entry. As for counting, just use an while loop and increment the counter. To know if the data entry stopped, i assume you have to make a guess. If the input is null `''`, then stop.

Comment: Another option is to store prev entry and check if current entry is  greater than prev. If not, then its not in alphabetic order

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
count = 0
prev = ''
isAlphabetical = True
while True:
  curr = input('Enter string:')
  if curr == '': # this is the ending condition. you may want to change it.
    break
  count+=1
  if curr < prev:
    isAlphabetical = False
  prev = curr

print('count =',count)
if isAlphabetical:
  print('they are in alphabetical order')
else:
  print('they are not in alphabetical order')
```

the above code takes the inputs until the user enters nothing and press the enter button. it takes track of the order of the inputs and the number of them.